# setValue Inside onDataChange

Tags: java, android, firebase

I try to set a new value from inside `onDataChange` on firebase but when i try to set a new value on a variable inside real-time database the android studio mark the `setValue()` method with red and says `Cannot resolve method 'setValue' in 'DataSnapshot'`

**Here is the part of my code:**

```
like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_emoji);
                    postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            // get post id \\
                            PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
                            String post_id = postModel.getId();

                            // get current likes from db \\
                            String currentLikes = snapshot.child(post_id).child("likes").getValue().toString();
                            int currentLikesToInt = Integer.parseInt(currentLikes);

                            // set new current likes on db \\
                            int newCurrentLikes = currentLikesToInt + 1;
                            snapshot.child(post_id).child("likes").setValue(newCurrentLikes);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `setValue()` on `DataSnapshot` , which is the value firebase just retrieved for you. What you need to do is use your `database reference`. In this case, it would be something like this:

```
postRef.child(post_id).child("likes").setValue(yourValue);
```

Hoping that `postRef` is a reference to a database where `post_id` and `likes` can be found. For more information on this read [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, simply change the following line of code:

```
snapshot.child(post_id).child("likes").setValue(newCurrentLikes);
```

To:

```
snapshot.child(post_id).child("likes").getRef().setValue(newCurrentLikes);
```

The [getRef()](http://getRef()) method is apart of the Query class:

> Returns:

> A DatabaseReference to this location